# ArrayAdapter possibly causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am having a problem moving forward with my app. I just started developing the app and only have about 15 hours involved so far. But I have hit a snag. Usually I am able to google snags and most of my answers come from this forum!

so I hope I can find a solution for this. Below is my activity java file. This is where the issue is as it was working fine before. I have been having a ton of trouble with showing my list using an array adapter.

```
public class Favorites extends Activity{
UserFunctions userFunctions  = new UserFunctions();
ArrayList<String> zipcodes = new ArrayList<String>(0);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 =      
         new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,zipcodes);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favoritespage);

    new DownloadDataTask().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

   private class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, JSONArray, ArrayList<String> > {


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(JSONArray... params) {
            JSONArray json = userFunctions.ziplistrequest("37.5", "140.45", "20");

            for(int i=0; i < json.length() ; i++) {
                JSONObject jarray = null;
                try {
                    jarray = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String zip = jarray.getString("ZIPCODE");
                    zipcodes.add(zip);
                    arrayAdapter1.add(zip);
                    Log.d(zip,"Output");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return zipcodes;
        }   
        protected void onPostExecute(){
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
        }
    }
```

}

Now I do not know what is causing my problem exactly. I have tried googling individual parts of the trace to no avail. I find many articles on it but each one presents it completely different than I have mine so their solution does not work for me. Below is the trace.

```
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lo/com.example.lo.Favorites}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4463)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:104)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at com.example.lo.Favorites.<init>(Favorites.java:33)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
01-29 07:55:47.753: E/AndroidRuntime(3723):     ... 11 more
```

I will be trying to fix this in the meantime. I think I am the only one who would rather program than watch the superbowl :P

Comment: how couldn't you google this snag... it's so common...

Comment: first I did not know what I was looking for, and second I do not understand it which makes it hard searching for an answer.

Comment: next time paste the error on google. `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your class, keep

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1;
```

and move the rest so it looks like this:

```
arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Favorites.this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,zipcodes);
```

to `onCreate()` or in `onPostExecute()`, depending on what exactly you want to do with the data.

The exception is thrown because `Adapter`s (and many Android components) need certain (behind the scenes) things initialized in the Activity. However, these things don't happen before the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` is called since `onCreate()` is the beginning of the [Activity's lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png).

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate that you explained it to me as well as provided a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,zipcodes);
```

You cannot use `this` in a call to `new ArrayAdapter()` until the activity has been initialized properly. You can assign to `arrayAdapter1` inside `onCreate()` (after calling `super.onCreate()`, or inside your `DownloadDataTask`. It would be better to do this inside `onPostExecute` instead of in `doInBackground`.